# Shifting level voltage of a signal

Tags: level-shifting, low-pass, decoupling-capacitor, coupling, filtering

I have a signal, which can vary from  400 to 7000 Hz approximately. It is a kind of pwm signal and has the time of high level, Ton, 30 times longer than the time of low level, Toff.  The shape of the wave is not so relevant, allowing some level of distortion without major problems. High level is 12 and low level is 0V.

I know that when we have a square signal and Ton = Toff, we can use a capacitor in series to stop the DC level, in other words, perform AC coupling only.  This makes the signal approximately symmetrical, positively and negatively.

However, for case in question, Ton is  greater than Toff, as I mentioned, and the capacitor  is not working, I used 10nF and 100nF capacitors, none of them worked.  I would like it swings from - 6V to 6V, aproximatelly.

Does someone has a simple  idea of how to do it? About source voltage, I just have positive ones, of 12 and 5 volts.

**EDITED:**

I tried the following circuit:

[image]

I had the following results of nodes 1, 2 and 3, respectively:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the load you're driving? One solution is a DC-restoring clamp on the output, but its form may change depending on the load. Is Ton always 30x longer than Toff, or does the mark space ratio vary? With a fixed m/s ratio, a simple voltage may suffice. How accurately must the output hit the +/- 6V levels? Does the 12v drive swing change, by much, a lot, not at all?

Comment: @Neil_UK, the load is car ECUs, not a specific one. The signal is imitating the phase signal of a phonic wheel. Ton is not always 30x longer, it can vary, but the most of them are near this ratio. I don't know how accurate it needs to be, but It does not need to be very accurate

Comment: @Neil_UK  about the DC-Restoring clamp, I don't know if I understood your answer very well, sorry if I don't, but I don't want to restore DC,  I want to remove it.

Comment: You want to set the output to +/-6V, when it isn't naturally, that process is called 'DC-restoration', from its history in the video industry. Unfortunately, ECU means as much to me as DC clamp does to you. How does an ECU behave? Does it look like a resistor to ground, and if so, of what value? Or a resistor to some other voltage. The details will govern how the clamp must be built. If you don't know you may need to experiment, which either means an oscilloscope to see what's happening, or blind 'build-it-and-try-it' does it work testing.

Comment: @Neil_UK, I don't know exactly the input resistance of an ECU (Electronic Central Unit), but I guess the input can be viwed as a resistor to ground

Comment: @Neil_UK, I change the capacitor, I choose a bigger one,  increase the load value and simulation worked fine. I will try to mount a circuit to test with a real load

Answer (score 2):

> Does someone has a simple idea of how to do it?

Simple is usually best.

> High level is 12 and low level is 0V.

Subtract 6 volts DC from the signal using an op-amp circuit. There are plenty of examples on the internet - go google op-amp mixers.

> About source voltage, I just have positive ones, of 12 and 5 volts.

You need to generate a negative supply voltage and, again, there are plenty of examples on the internet. Google inverting buck regulator or inverting charge pump or isolating DC/DC converters.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what your load is. Let's assume the simplest possible, which is a high value resistor to ground. This is reasonable as the desire is a +/- 6V waveform.

As the signal spends much longer (23x times for simple mental arithmetic) in the high state than the low, the output of a series coupling capacitor will tend to be 0.5V for most of the time and -11.5V during the off time. This is because the combination of load resistor and coupling capacitor averages the area under the curve.

A possible solution is to 'clamp' the negative swing to -6V. At this frequency, this is most conveniently done with a zener diode to set the voltage. However, zeners act like a normal diode in the other direction, so an additional diode is needed to stop that. Use a 5.1V or 5.6V zener in series with a small signal diode between ground and signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzZiy6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As it's a negative clamp, I've drawn it with the voltage convention of positive upwards, it draws current from ground to inject into the node when that node is negative. That means I know I've got the diodes the right way round.

Comment: Interesting, but how to clamp it to - 6V? I don't have negative source voltages.

Comment: You don't need a -6V source, your only connection is to ground. The '-6V' is provided by the 12V down swing of the input signal, which would normally take the output down to -11.5V, being clamped to only go to -6V (or thereabouts) by the two diodes. The 12V upswing now takes the output voltage to +6V. All this time, the resistive load 'trys' to take the output more negative, it's pulling current from the node when it's high, which is why the diodes are needed to supply this current from ground during the low times.

Comment: very interesting! I will mount it later today , unfortunatelly I can't do it now, but I will inform the result here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I did the circuit you suggested, I used LTspice to simulate and it didn't have 5.6V zener model, so, I used a 6.2V model. It seems that the capacitor does not have enough charge to sustain voltage on the load.

Comment: I set up the circuit and found that the ECU has a pull up of 5V, so the voltage on the load started at 6V, discharge quickly to 5V during Ton, during Toff the voltage drops to about - 5v and then charges again. I tried to use a electrolitical capacitor to increase the response and it worked, but the negative voltage only reached aproximately - 3V

Comment: @Daniel If the load pullup is to 5v, then without the clamp, and assuming the +5v can sink current too, the simple series cap will settle to a +5.5V -6.5V swing (assuming 23:1 m/s ratio). Would that be adequate? Does that happen? Do you have a 'scope to check?

Comment: I was wrong, it does not pullup.  I'm thinking about, I will need to use this circuit to a variety of ECUs and now I have the information that not all will need signals with the same timing characteristics, I mean, the frequency range remains the same, but the pulse width ratio ( Ton/Toff)  can vary.

Answer (score 1):

Generate yourself a -ve 12V rail using an ICL7660A (The 'A' version will do -12V from +12V). Then implement the bottom circuit below.

[image: Voltage shifter]

Comment: Oops - opamp inputs on both my circuits are labelled the wrong way around - swap them over!

Comment: It is a good idea. I have a ICL7660A  with me. But, I read the datasheet and I'm afraid that the current decreases a lot. I mean, the input voltage to the ICL7660A  will be 12V, the output will be -12V, I'm afraid of the output current decreases to something near 0mA, no ? Figure 7 of page 6 of the datasheet reinforce this idea.

Comment: I see what you mean, I hadn't spotted that. I would try configuring the ICL7660A as I suggest with a +12V input and  see, with the load current that the circuit draws, if the ICL7660A's output will hold up to a reasonable negative voltage. The output signal only goes down to -6V so if the ICL7660A's output will provide a negative voltage between -6V and -12V, at the required load current with an input of 12V then it may provide the solution you are after. I'd try it and see.